# Foreach loop failure

Tags: php, loops

The first loop gets the 2 values for hostkarma just fine. The 2nd loop fails for accredit.habeas and I get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 11". Where am I going wroge with the "foreach($value as $val)" loop?

```
$hosts = array('209.49.180.233','209.49.180.234');
foreach ($hosts as $host)                    // Loop for IP addresses
{
    $rbls = array('hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com','accredit.habeas.com');
    foreach ($rbls as $rbl)                  // Loop for domains
    {
        $hostname = gethostbyaddr( $host );
        $lookup = $hostname . '.' . $rbl;
        $value = gethostbynamel($lookup);
    foreach($value as $val)                  // loop for multiple record/code values
            {
                echo $host, $rbl, $val . "
";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use var_dump($value) and send us plz.

Comment: From PHP manual for `gethostbynamel`: _Returns an **array** of IPv4 addresses or **FALSE** if hostname could not be resolved._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add:

```
if (is_array($value))
```

just before `foreach($value as $val)` line.

For the cases when `gethostbynamel` is failing its return value `$value` is not an array hence causing `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error.

Comment: @JT: On the top-left corner of this answer below number "3" there is a tick mark, you just need to click on that.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that [gethostbynamel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) returns FALSE if cannot resolve the hostname and that [gethostbyaddr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) returns the unmodified ip address on failure.

So check the results that are being returned by these functions and do something sensible if one of them fails.